# Reciprocal of $\frac {x}{y} - 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

What is the reciprocal of $\frac {x}{y} - 1?$ Isn’t it $\frac {y}{(x - y)}?$ But I don’t see this answer in the multiple choice.

$\frac {x}{y} - 1$ = $\frac {x - y}{y}$ and reciprocal is $\frac {y}{x - y}$.

Edited: My apologies for not providing complete question. The question is as below:
"Which of the following equals the reciprocal of $\frac {x}{y} - 1$, where $\frac {x}{y} - 1$ does not equal to 0?"

The choices of the answers are (A) $\frac {1}{x} - y$, (B) -$\frac {y}{x}$, (C) $\frac{y}{x-1}$, (D) $\frac{x}{xy-1}$ and (E) $\frac{y}{xy-1}$.

Comment: This is not clear.  Do you mean $\frac x{y-1}$ or $\frac xy -1$?

Comment: @lulu Due to the order of operations, bison72 means the latter. It's also clear from "x/y - 1 = (x - y)/y".

Comment: @Shaun  Well, maybe.  Or perhaps that is the source of the confusion.

Comment: What responses did they give?  Your work is fine.

Comment: @lulu When you look at it like that, it's clear what you mean.

Comment: Please provide the complete question. The term $\frac{y}{x-y}$ can be manipulated in many ways.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are correct. Given that $\frac{x}{y}-1 = \frac{x-y}{y}$, then the reciprocal is $\frac{y}{x-y}$.

If this answer is not one of the options, maybe realise that this fraction is equal to $1- \frac{x}{x-y}$.

Comment: The choices of the answers are (A) 1/x -y , (B) -y/x, (C) y/(x-1), (D) x/(xy-1) and (E)  y/(xy-1). The original question asked is "Which of the following equals the reciprocal of x/y - 1, where x/y - 1 does not equal to 0". Does that mean something else?

Comment: @bison72: Those choices should be included in your question, not just as a comment.